# Estimate lower incomplete gamma function $\left|\gamma(n,z)-\gamma(n,-z)\right|$.

Tags: inequality, special-functions

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), the upper incomplete gamma function is defined as:
$$\Gamma(s,x) = \int_x^{\infty} t^{s-1}\,e^{-t}\,{\rm d}t ,\,\!$$
whereas the lower incomplete gamma function is defined as:
$$\gamma(s,x) = \int_0^x t^{s-1}\,e^{-t}\,{\rm d}t .\,\!$$
I'm trying to estimate from above
$$\left|\gamma(n,z)-\gamma(n,-z)\right|$$
where $n\in\mathbb N$ and $z$ is an imaginary number but I have no idea.

Any suggestions please?